# ML.NET trying the model with sample data from csv file

Tags: c#, machine-learning, dataview, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

Trying to predict a value by giving the model a sample data. In ML.NET it automatically selects the first row of the training data as sample data. I want to select another row or rows but I cant write the values by hand because there are too many columns(239 to be exact).

I tried converting the data which I read from a csv file to IEnumerable and then predict each using foreach.

```
var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<MLModel1.ModelInput (@"csv file path", ';', true);

IEnumerable<MLModel1.ModelInput> dataEnumerable = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<MLModel1.ModelInput>(data, reuseRowObject: false);

foreach (var item in dataEnumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Gerçek Puan: " + item.Puan);
    var sortedScoresWithLabel = MLModel1.PredictAllLabels(item);
    Console.WriteLine($"{"Class",-40}{"Score",-20}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{"-----",-40}{"-----",-20}");

    foreach (var score in sortedScoresWithLabel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{score.Key,-40}{score.Value,-20}");
    }
}
```

It works but CreateEnumerable method converts some values to NaN randomly. Is there a fix?

[values are like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ81Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without seeing some example data, but it looks like some of your features are strings so its possible some contain a stray ";" that is messing up the column ordering, or you have actual null values.

I'd simply try re-creating you data so every field is quoted (unless it already is), and then use optional allowQuoting in LoadFromTextFile() and then give it another go, e.g

```
var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<MLModel1.ModelInput (@"csv file path", ';', true, allowQuoting: true);
```

allowQuoting also changes the behavior of how missing values are treated, with its false as yours currently is missing values *could* be getting loaded in as null, "When false, empty values are denoted by consecutive separators and missing values by the **default missing value** for each type"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textloadersavercatalog.loadfromtextfile?view=ml-dotnet